# How far away does a hot body influence its environment?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, thermal-radiation, thermal-conductivity

I am very curious how far can we detect a hot object's temperature influence on the enviroment?

For example, if we have a 100 degree celsius round metalic ball in a room that is 30 degree celsius. Let's assume that it's normal atmospheric pressure, and there is normal air in the room.

**At what distance from the metalic ball does the temperature take the average temperature of the room (it's influence reaches 0)?**

Is there a formula for this? I assume it decreases proportionally with the distance in a power-law curve, until it hits the average temperature of the room.

Comment: I think that there is some confused thinking in the question "how far can we detect a hot object's temperature, before it dissipates into the enviroment's temperature?" and perhaps it should read "how far away does a hot body influence its environment?"  The answer then very much depends on the environment as to whether the transfer of energy from the hot body is via conduction and/or convection and/or radiation.

Comment: Ok thanks for suggestion, edited the post. Indeed I am curious what is the distance from an object where it's temperature influence reaches 0. I need a formula of some sort.

Comment: AFAIK there's no clear answer to this.  Do you want when it's within 0.001 degree?  I'm pretty sure it always has an increasingly small influence unless there's some fundamental energy size you can't go below.

Comment: I let you pick an arbitrary treshold. But I would just like a general formula to work with.

Comment: What do you ask? [ temperature of the air/infrared sensor aimed to the metallic ball/ subjective feeling of heat on the skin]. Maybe the latest- where do you not recognize the  heat by your skin? Then you will have some $Area_{ball} \times (T-T0)^4/R^2$ dependence, but the skin sensitivity needs some more thinking

Comment: @visitor0777 You  would want to look at the topic of "heat transfer".  If you assumed the ball was constantly at 100 degrees (i.e. something was keeping it heated) then you would want steady state heat transfer (probably 1-dimensional).  You would need to know what you want the temperature of (is it an object? it it just air temperature?).  The temperature influence depends on both the ball and what it is trying to influence.  Without more information we can't give a very complete answer.

Answer (score -1):

We detect the temperature by the frequency of light it emits. You can't really measure temperature easily in other ways, unless you measure it with direct contact.

Comment: I need a general formula, for an average situation (atmospheric pressure, air as thermal conductor)